# PHP Custom Markup Language Parser

Tags: php, html, markup

I am making a website, and I would like to make a custom Markup type language in PHP. I want the tags to be surrounded with `[` and `]`. Now, I was thinking about this, like anyone would, and I could do something like this:

```
function formatMarkup($markup = ''){
    $markup = str_replace('[color=blue]', '<span style="color: blue">', $markup);
    return $markup
}
```

Even though that might work, it would be more progrematically correct if it would do something like `explode()`, but starting at every `[` and ending at every `]`. This would be great if I found out. Thank you for your time and effort.

**EDIT:**
I have decided to use `preg_split()`. It seems nice, and all, but I cannot get the regex. [Here is my code](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/fb9).

**EDIT #2:**
I have got most of the regex done, but there are uneeded extra keys in the array. How would I fix them? [Here is my new code](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/fba).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made my Markup language. I used

```
$split = preg_split("/(\[|\])/", $markup);
```

to get the individual "tags" and used

```
foreach($split as $k => $v){
        if(strlen($v) < 1){
            continue;
        }
```

to illiterate through each of them, and check if the value is empty. Then, after that, I would do all of my checks, and parse the code blocks together, and make line, after line, the re-constructed text.